# SH Script to Rename .apk.odex files

Tags: apk, shell, bash, odex

I have written a script to utilize dexopt-wrapper to odex a folder of .apk's

```
#!/bin/sh

SYSAPP=/mnt/extSdCard/FilesToOdex/system/app/
SYSPRIVAPP=/mnt/extSdCard/FilesToOdex/system/priv-app/

for i1 in $SYSAPP*.apk ; do
        echo "Odexing $i1..."
        dexopt-wrapper $i1 $i1.odex
done

for i2 in $SYSPRIVAPP*.apk ; do
        echo "Odexing $i2..."
        dexopt-wrapper $i2 $i2.odex
done


for file1 in $SYSAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "$file1" "`basename $file1 .apk.odex`$file1.odex"
done
for file2 in $SYSPRIVAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "$file2" "`basename $file2 .apk.odex`$file2.odex"
done
```

The odexing part works, but as you can see it creates a bunch of .apk.odex files

So my question is:

1. How can I setup the odexing portion to not write the files out as *.apk.odex?
2. **OR**, How can I get the `mv` to properly rename the *.apk.odex files to be just *.odex files?

I tried:

```
for file1 in $SYSAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "${file1}" "${file1%.odex}" 
done
for file2 in $SYSPRIVAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "${file2}" "${file2%.odex}"
done
```

but it turned all my .apk.odex files to .apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's rather a shell scripting question to be asked at [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Your answer can be found here: [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/2533433):

```
for file1 in $SYSAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "${file1}" "${file1%.*}.odex" 
done
for file2 in $SYSPRIVAPP*.apk.odex; do
    mv "${file2}" "${file2%.*}.odex"
done
```

should work on most shells, supposedly.

**Update:**

You can even omit half of your script by adapting this to your original statements: `dexopt-wrapper $i1 ${i1%.*}.odex` should create the file with the correct naming, so no need to rename it later. To make your script real short and handy:

```
#!/bin/sh
SYSAPP=/mnt/extSdCard/FilesToOdex/system/app/
SYSPRIVAPP=/mnt/extSdCard/FilesToOdex/system/priv-app/

for i1 in $SYSAPP*.apk $SYSPRIVAPP*.apk; do
    echo "Odexing $i1..."
    dexopt-wrapper $i1 ${i1%.*}.odex
done
```

That's all you should need :)

Comment: I thought about the rename function as well...  on my device it does seem that it is included.  I will try this out in a few minutes

Comment: It can be done even easier, see my update ;)

Comment: hot digity!  That did the trick... now if I can figure out how to get this same script to open up the .apk and remove the classes.dex from it, I'll really be in business LOL

Comment: Well, that definitely is beyond a) the scope of this site and b) my knowledge (modifying the `.apk` itself would break its trust, as you don't have the original key to re-sign it). But glad I was able to help a little at least ;)

Comment: :)   Yeah, I can go through them on my Linux box open them to browse as .zip files, and remove them that way   Much obliged for this!